# Como encontrar uma informação dentro de um procedure no sql?

Tags: sql

Então, eu precisava achar uma coluna dentro de um procedure, o problema é que não sei qual procedure é

Então queria saber se tem um select para buscar informação dentro dela

Ex:

```
procedure{
insert into tabelax (tabela) values ('')
}
```

Queria saber qual procedure faz o insert por exemplo na "tabela" ou "coluna"

Comment: qual o banco de dados?

Answer (score -3):

insert into [nome da tabela] (nome das colunas onde você vai inserir informação) values (valores que você quer colocar, na mesma ordem da lista de colunas.)

Exemplo, você tem uma tabela que guarda nome e idade das pessoas o comando seria.

insert into pessoas (nome,idade) value ('João',10)

Assim você insere dados em uma tabela.